# Show List of Products from sql in between blog content in codeigniter using tinymce

Tags: tinymce, codeigniter-3, blogs

i am working on a blog system for my travel project on codeigniter. i am using tinymce for entering blog content.
one thing, i want is - display a list of travel packages from sql results in between those content.

how to achieve this using codeigniter and tinymce.
i have tried searching for threads and forums, but couldn't find anything related to it.

i hope someone can help me in this here.

i hope this screenshot can help in understand that what i want.
[Reference to the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOPjg.png)

Comment: Read the Codeigniter user guide for starters. Or look up some tutorials of which there are many.

Comment: yes i am trying to look up for shortcodes parser library like wordpress, i am just trying if that helps. it will be great if you can throw some tutorial links here. i am just stucked at this.